# How to properly handle Fluent NHibernate closure with .Select()

Tags: c#, nhibernate, closures

I am working on a C# project that was created as a resful service, implementing NHibernate and StructureMap.  I am running into an issue that I believe is closure related that is causing a serious problem. (I did not write this code, just found the bug).

As you can see in the sample below, a route is established that accepts parameters to filter an nhibernate query.  The problem is that the first time the route is hit, the filter object is created and populated, then sent to the select() where a function is executed on the item using the filters to filter the results.  However the second time that the route is hit, the new filter object is NOT getting sent to the function being called!  When breakpoints are set i can see the filter object within the function changing back to the old data from the first time the route was called.  I have not dealt with closures in C# like this that are nexted two levels down, and it appears that adding a body to the .Select() lamba expression is not allowed, the error is "a lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree".  I have more of the code that this function uses but its not really relevant to the question (I dont think).  I guess the question is what is the proper way to handle this with C#.  Thanks for any help!

```
[Route("RwaOffBalance/{bankId:int}/{month:int?}/{year:int?}")]
public dynamic Get(int bankId, int month = 0, int year = 0)
{
    var filters = new RwaFilterCriteria {BankId = bankId, Month = month, Year = year};
    return Get(() => 
        Repository.Create<OffBalanceSheetItemDescriptionLookup>()
            .Where(x => x.Active)
            .Select(item => GetOffBalances(filters, item))
            .ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar situation. It seems NHibernate's LINQ provider isn't properly dealing with closure variables used in inline lambda expressions, but instead bakes in the value that it received when it first interpreted the expression tree.

One workaround is to do a ToList() directly after your Where(), and then do the Select() after that. That will cause the IQueryable to be evaluated before your Select() gets applied. This undoubtedly uses more memory though since you are creating two lists with the complete data set.

Another workaround is to pre-define your lambda outside of the select. NHibernate's LINQ provider can call local functions properly. Ex:

```
var filters = new RwaFilterCriteria {BankId = bankId, Month = month, Year = year};
Func<ItemType, ResultType> selectFunc = item => GetOffBalances(filters, item);
return Get(() => 
    Repository.Create<OffBalanceSheetItemDescriptionLookup>()
        .Where(x => x.Active)
        .Select(selectFunc)
        .ToList());
```

**Update**: It's also worth noting that this isn't specific to Fluent NHibernate. The LINQ provider is built in to NHibernate core. I have submitted an issue against NHibernate for this: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3673

**Update 2**: Another workaround is to call AsEnumerable() to evaluate the SQL query:

```
Repository.Create<OffBalanceSheetItemDescriptionLookup>()
    .Where(x => x.Active)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(item => GetOffBalances(filters, item)
    .ToList()
```